# PHP submit button not submitting

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, button

I have a formpage which is supposed to submit the form data to an ajaxrequest. this has worked continuously but suddenly stopped working. it doesn't write error messages to the log it just does nothing.

image of the page that houses the button:
[submission page in dutch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pS2FN.png)
I have tried to look at what changes i made to the file and the only thing that i changed was a ; which i returned to it's original position
here is the code that contains the button:

```
<Formik
        initialValues={getInitialFormData()}
        onSubmit={onFormSubmit}
        validationSchema={FormSchema}
        render={({ values, errors }) => (
          <Form>
            <FormFieldsWrapper disabled={fieldsDisabled}>
              <Section>
                <SectionHeading>
                  Basis informatie
                </SectionHeading>

                <FieldsRow>
                  <FieldsColumn size='half'>
                    <Field
                      name='name'
                      label='Schoolnaam'
                      placeholder='Vul schoolnaam in'
                      component={FormTextField}
                    />
                  </FieldsColumn>

                  <FieldsColumn size='half'>
                    <Field
                      name='address'
                      label='Schooladres'
                      placeholder='Vul schooladres in'
                      component={FormTextField}
                    />
                  </FieldsColumn>
                </FieldsRow>

                <FieldsRow>
                  <FieldsColumn size='third'>
                    <Field
                      name='region'
                      label='Region'
                      placeholder='Selecteer regio'
                      hideDropdownIcon={fieldsDisabled}
                      component={FormSelectField}
                      options={regionOptions}
                    />
                  </FieldsColumn>

                  <FieldsColumn size='third'>
                    <Field
                      name='contact_name'
                      label='Contactpersoon'
                      placeholder='Vul contactnaam in'
                      component={FormTextField}
                    />
                  </FieldsColumn>

                  <FieldsColumn size='third'>
                    <Field
                      name='contact_email'
                      label='e-mailadres'
                      placeholder='Vul contact e-mailadres in'
                      component={FormTextField}
                    />
                  </FieldsColumn>
                </FieldsRow>
              </Section>

              <Section>
                <SectionHeading noMarginBottom>
                  Groep
                </SectionHeading>

                <FieldArray
                  name='classes'
                  render={arrayHelpers => (
                    <>
                      {values.classes.map((item, index) => {
                        const productionId = get(values, `classes[${index}].production_id`);
                        return (
                          <FieldsArrayWrapper key={index}>
                            <ReactTooltip />
  
                            {!fieldsDisabled && (
                              <RemoveRowButton
                                onClick={() => {
                                  if(confirm('Dient deze groep verwijdert te worden?')) {
                                    arrayHelpers.remove(index)
                                  }
                                }}
                              >
                                &times;
                              </RemoveRowButton>
                            )}
  
                            <FieldsRow>
                              <FieldsColumn size='third'>
                                <Field
                                  name={`classes[${index}].level`}
                                  label={(
                                    <span data-tip='Vul hier aub per groep het juiste leerlingaantal in. Combinatiegroepen dienen per unieke groep te worden ingevoerd.'>
                                      Groep
                                      <QuestionMarkIcon>
                                        ?
                                      </QuestionMarkIcon>
                                    </span>
                                  )}
                                  hideDropdownIcon={fieldsDisabled}
                                  component={FormSelectField}
                                  options={[
                                    { value: '1', text: 'Groep 1/2' },
                                    { value: '2', text: 'Groep 3' },
                                    { value: '3', text: 'Groep 4' },
                                    { value: '4', text: 'Groep 5' },
                                    { value: '5' , text: 'Groep 6' },
                                    { value: '6' , text: 'Groep 7' },
                                    { value: '7' , text: 'Groep 8' },
                                  ]}
                                />
                              </FieldsColumn>
                              
                              <FieldsColumn size='third'>
                                <Field
                                  name={`classes[${index}].students_count`}
                                  label='Aantal leerlingen'
                                  placeholder='Vul aantal leerlingen in'
                                  type='number'
                                  min='1'
                                  component={FormTextField}
                                />
                              </FieldsColumn>
  
                              <FieldsColumn size='third'>
                                {(
                                  !Boolean(loginCode) ||
                                  (
                                    Boolean(loginCode) &&
                                    productionId !== '' &&
                                    productionId !== '0' &&
                                    productionId !== undefined
                                  )
                                ) && (
                                  <Field
                                    name={`classes[${index}].production_id`}
                                    label='Productie'
                                    placeholder='Kies de productie'
                                    hideDropdownIcon={fieldsDisabled}
                                    component={FormSelectField}
                                    options={productionOptions}
                                  />
                                )}
                              </FieldsColumn>
                            </FieldsRow>
  
                            {Boolean(loginCode) && (
                              <>
                                <EventInfoHeading>
                                  Voorstelling informatie
                                </EventInfoHeading>
                                
                                <FieldsRow>
                                  <FieldsColumn size='half'>
                                    <Field
                                      name={`classes[${index}].event_display_date`}
                                      label='Datum en tijd voorstelling'
                                      component={FormTextField}
                                      disabled
                                    />
                                  </FieldsColumn>
  
                                  <FieldsColumn size='half'>
                                    <Field
                                      name={`classes[${index}].event_address`}
                                      label='Adres voorstelling'
                                      component={FormTextField}
                                      disabled
                                    />
                                  </FieldsColumn>
                                </FieldsRow>
                              </>
                            )}
                          </FieldsArrayWrapper>
                        )
                      })}
                      
                      {!fieldsDisabled && (
                        <Button
                          type="button"
                          addClass
                          onClick={() => arrayHelpers.push({
                            first_name: '',
                            last_name: '',
                            students_count: 1,
                            level: '1',
                            production_id: '',
                            event_display_date: '',
                            event_address: '',
                          })}
                        >
                          Voeg groep toe
                        </Button>
                      )}

                      {typeof errors.classes === 'string' && (
                        <FieldErrorMessage>
                          {errors.classes}
                        </FieldErrorMessage>
                      )}
                    </>
                  )
                }
                />
              </Section>
            </FormFieldsWrapper>
            
            {!loginCode && (
              <Field
                name='terms'
                label={(
                  <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: get(__STP_DATA, 'options.terms_checkbox_text', '') }} />
                )}
                component={FormCheckbox}
              />
            )}

            {!loginCode && (
              <FormButtons>
                {fieldsDisabled && (
                  <>
                    <Button
                      cancelButton
                      onClick={() => {
                        setFieldsDisabled(false);
                      }}
                    >
                      Cancel
                    </Button>

                    <Button 
                      submitButton
                      onClick={onConfirmClick}
                    >
                      Bevestig
                    </Button>
                  </>
                )}

                {!fieldsDisabled && (
                  <Button type="submit" submitButton>
                    Verzend
                  </Button>
                )}
              </FormButtons>
            )}
          </Form>
        )}
      />
```

and it is a problem regarding this button specifically:

```
{!fieldsDisabled && (
                  <Button type="submit" submitButton>
                    Verzend
                  </Button>
                )}
```

I've been pulling my hair out because i simply can't pinpoint the issue
I'll also add the complete formpage code if that helps:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import ReactTooltip from 'react-tooltip';
import { Formik, Form, Field, FieldArray } from 'formik';
import get from 'lodash/get';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import { ajaxRequest } from '../../../helpers';
import {
  Wrapper,
  BackLink,
  Title,
  Section,
  SectionHeading,
  FieldsRow,
  FieldsColumn,
  FormTextField,
  FormTextAreaField,
  FormSelectField,
  Button,
  RemoveRowButton,
  FieldErrorMessage,
  FieldsArrayWrapper,
  FormFieldsWrapper,
  QuestionMarkIcon,
  FormButtons,
  EventInfoHeading,
  FormCheckbox,
} from './styled';

const FormSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  name: Yup.string().required('Schoolnaam is verplicht'),
  address: Yup.string().required('Schooladres is verplicht'),
  region: Yup.string().required('Schoolregio is verplicht'),
  contact_name: Yup.string().required('Contactnaam is verplicht'),
  contact_email: Yup.string().email('contact e-mail is incorrect').required('contact e-mail is verplicht'),
  classes: Yup.array().of(
    Yup.object().shape({
      first_name: Yup.string().required(`Voornaam leraar is verplich`),
      last_name: Yup.string().required(`Achternaam leraar is verplicht`),
      students_count: Yup.string().required('Aantal leerlingen is verplicht'),
      level: Yup.string().required('Groepsniveau is verplicht'),
    })
  ).required('Tenminste 1 groep dient er te worden opgegeven'),
  terms: Yup.boolean().oneOf([true], 'You must accept terms and conditions'),
});

const RequestChangeFormSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  message: Yup.string().required('Bericht is verplicht'),
});

const FormPage = ({ history, match: { params: { loginCode } } }) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [fieldsDisabled, setFieldsDisabled] = useState(false);
  const [submittedValues, setSubmittedValues] = useState({});
  const [ajaxData, setAjaxData] = useState({});

  const getInitialFormData = () => {
    if(loginCode && ajaxData && ajaxData.formData) {
      const {
        formData: {
          school: {
            name,
            address,
            region,
            contact_name,
            contact_email,
          },
          classes,
        }
      } = ajaxData;

      return {
        name,
        address,
        region,
        contact_name,
        contact_email,
        classes: classes.map(({
          students_count,
          age_group,
          production_id,
          event,
        }) => ({
          students_count,
          level: age_group,
          production_id: production_id || '',
          event_display_date: (event && event.formatted_datetime) ? event.formatted_datetime : 'Niet ingevuld',
          event_address: event ? event.address : 'Niet ingevuld',
        })),
        terms: false,
      }
    }

    return {
      name: '',
      address: '',
      region: 'region-1',
      contact_name: '',
      contact_email: '',
      classes: [
        {
          students_count: 1,
          level: '1',
          production_id: '',
          event_display_date: '',
          event_address: '',
        }
      ],
      terms: false,
    };
  }

  const onBackButtonClick = () => {
    history.push('/');
  };

  const onFormSubmit = (values, { setSubmitting }) => {
    if(!fieldsDisabled) {
      setFieldsDisabled(true);
      setSubmitting(false);
      setSubmittedValues(values);
    }
  };

  const onRequestChangeSubmit = async (values, { resetForm }) => {
    const success = await ajaxRequest({
      action: 'stp_request_change',
      data: {
        message: values.message,
        login_code: loginCode,
      },
      formatData: ({ success }) => success,
    });

    if(success) {
      alert('Bericht is verzonden');
      resetForm();
    } else {
      alert('Het is niet mogelijk het bericht te verzenden');
    }
  };

  const onConfirmClick = () => {
    ajaxRequest({
      action: 'stp_add_school_data',
      data: {
        ...submittedValues,
      },
      formatData: (data) => {
        if(data && data.success && data.data && data.data.login_code) {
          history.push(`/school/${data.data.login_code}`);
        }
      },
    });
    setLoading(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      try {
        const dataRequests = [
          ajaxRequest({
            action: 'stp_get_all_productions',
            formatData: data => data,
          }),
          ajaxRequest({
            action: 'stp_get_all_regions',
            formatData: data => data,
          })
        ]

        if(loginCode) {
          dataRequests.push(
            ajaxRequest({
              action: 'stp_get_form_data',
              data: {
                login_code: loginCode,
              },
              formatData: data => data,
            })
          );
        }

        const [
          productions,
          regions,
          formData,
        ] = await Promise.all(dataRequests);
    
        setAjaxData({
          productions: productions.data,
          regions: regions.data,
          formData: loginCode && formData && formData.success ? formData.data : null,
        });
  
        if(loginCode) {
          if(!formData || !formData.success) {
            history.push(`/`);
          } else {
            setFieldsDisabled(true);
          }
        }

        setLoading(false);
      } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
    
    setLoading(true);
    getData();
  }, [loginCode]);

  if(loading) {
    return <>Loading...</>;
  }

  if(
    !ajaxData.productions ||
    !ajaxData.productions.length ||
    !ajaxData.regions ||
    !ajaxData.regions.length
  ) {
    return <>Er is een fout opgetreden. Neem aub contact op met de Administrator</>;
  }

  const productionOptions = [
    { value: '', text: 'Geen productie' },
    ...(ajaxData.productions.map(({
      id,
      name,
    }) => ({
      value: id,
      text: name,
    }))),
  ];

  const regionOptions = [
    ...(ajaxData.regions.map(({
      id,
      name,
    }) => ({
      value: id,
      text: name,
    }))),
  ];

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <BackLink onClick={onBackButtonClick}>
        &#60; Back
      </BackLink>
  
      {!loginCode && (
        <Title>
          {!fieldsDisabled ? 'Vul hieronder de gegevens van uw school in.' : 'De volgende data is hieronder ingevuld. Bevestig aub dat deze data correct is'}
        </Title>
      )}

      {loginCode && (
        <Title>
          Informatie van de school met code: <strong>{loginCode}</strong>
        </Title>
      )}

      <Formik
        initialValues={getInitialFormData()}
        onSubmit={onFormSubmit}
        validationSchema={FormSchema}
        render={({ values, errors }) => (
          <Form>
            <FormFieldsWrapper disabled={fieldsDisabled}>
              <Section>
                <SectionHeading>
                  Basis informatie
                </SectionHeading>

                <FieldsRow>
                  <FieldsColumn size='half'>
                    <Field
                      name='name'
                      label='Schoolnaam'
                      placeholder='Vul schoolnaam in'
                      component={FormTextField}
                    />
                  </FieldsColumn>

                  <FieldsColumn size='half'>
                    <Field
                      name='address'
                      label='Schooladres'
                      placeholder='Vul schooladres in'
                      component={FormTextField}
                    />
                  </FieldsColumn>
                </FieldsRow>

                <FieldsRow>
                  <FieldsColumn size='third'>
                    <Field
                      name='region'
                      label='Region'
                      placeholder='Selecteer regio'
                      hideDropdownIcon={fieldsDisabled}
                      component={FormSelectField}
                      options={regionOptions}
                    />
                  </FieldsColumn>

                  <FieldsColumn size='third'>
                    <Field
                      name='contact_name'
                      label='Contactpersoon'
                      placeholder='Vul contactnaam in'
                      component={FormTextField}
                    />
                  </FieldsColumn>

                  <FieldsColumn size='third'>
                    <Field
                      name='contact_email'
                      label='e-mailadres'
                      placeholder='Vul contact e-mailadres in'
                      component={FormTextField}
                    />
                  </FieldsColumn>
                </FieldsRow>
              </Section>

              <Section>
                <SectionHeading noMarginBottom>
                  Groep
                </SectionHeading>

                <FieldArray
                  name='classes'
                  render={arrayHelpers => (
                    <>
                      {values.classes.map((item, index) => {
                        const productionId = get(values, `classes[${index}].production_id`);
                        return (
                          <FieldsArrayWrapper key={index}>
                            <ReactTooltip />
  
                            {!fieldsDisabled && (
                              <RemoveRowButton
                                onClick={() => {
                                  if(confirm('Dient deze groep verwijdert te worden?')) {
                                    arrayHelpers.remove(index)
                                  }
                                }}
                              >
                                &times;
                              </RemoveRowButton>
                            )}
  
                            <FieldsRow>
                              <FieldsColumn size='third'>
                                <Field
                                  name={`classes[${index}].level`}
                                  label={(
                                    <span data-tip='Vul hier aub per groep het juiste leerlingaantal in. Combinatiegroepen dienen per unieke groep te worden ingevoerd.'>
                                      Groep
                                      <QuestionMarkIcon>
                                        ?
                                      </QuestionMarkIcon>
                                    </span>
                                  )}
                                  hideDropdownIcon={fieldsDisabled}
                                  component={FormSelectField}
                                  options={[
                                    { value: '1', text: 'Groep 1/2' },
                                    { value: '2', text: 'Groep 3' },
                                    { value: '3', text: 'Groep 4' },
                                    { value: '4', text: 'Groep 5' },
                                    { value: '5' , text: 'Groep 6' },
                                    { value: '6' , text: 'Groep 7' },
                                    { value: '7' , text: 'Groep 8' },
                                  ]}
                                />
                              </FieldsColumn>
                              
                              <FieldsColumn size='third'>
                                <Field
                                  name={`classes[${index}].students_count`}
                                  label='Aantal leerlingen'
                                  placeholder='Vul aantal leerlingen in'
                                  type='number'
                                  min='1'
                                  component={FormTextField}
                                />
                              </FieldsColumn>
  
                              <FieldsColumn size='third'>
                                {(
                                  !Boolean(loginCode) ||
                                  (
                                    Boolean(loginCode) &&
                                    productionId !== '' &&
                                    productionId !== '0' &&
                                    productionId !== undefined
                                  )
                                ) && (
                                  <Field
                                    name={`classes[${index}].production_id`}
                                    label='Productie'
                                    placeholder='Kies de productie'
                                    hideDropdownIcon={fieldsDisabled}
                                    component={FormSelectField}
                                    options={productionOptions}
                                  />
                                )}
                              </FieldsColumn>
                            </FieldsRow>
  
                            {Boolean(loginCode) && (
                              <>
                                <EventInfoHeading>
                                  Voorstelling informatie
                                </EventInfoHeading>
                                
                                <FieldsRow>
                                  <FieldsColumn size='half'>
                                    <Field
                                      name={`classes[${index}].event_display_date`}
                                      label='Datum en tijd voorstelling'
                                      component={FormTextField}
                                      disabled
                                    />
                                  </FieldsColumn>
  
                                  <FieldsColumn size='half'>
                                    <Field
                                      name={`classes[${index}].event_address`}
                                      label='Adres voorstelling'
                                      component={FormTextField}
                                      disabled
                                    />
                                  </FieldsColumn>
                                </FieldsRow>
                              </>
                            )}
                          </FieldsArrayWrapper>
                        )
                      })}
                      
                      {!fieldsDisabled && (
                        <Button
                          type="button"
                          addClass
                          onClick={() => arrayHelpers.push({
                            first_name: '',
                            last_name: '',
                            students_count: 1,
                            level: '1',
                            production_id: '',
                            event_display_date: '',
                            event_address: '',
                          })}
                        >
                          Voeg groep toe
                        </Button>
                      )}

                      {typeof errors.classes === 'string' && (
                        <FieldErrorMessage>
                          {errors.classes}
                        </FieldErrorMessage>
                      )}
                    </>
                  )
                }
                />
              </Section>
            </FormFieldsWrapper>
            
            {!loginCode && (
              <Field
                name='terms'
                label={(
                  <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: get(__STP_DATA, 'options.terms_checkbox_text', '') }} />
                )}
                component={FormCheckbox}
              />
            )}

            {!loginCode && (
              <FormButtons>
                {fieldsDisabled && (
                  <>
                    <Button
                      cancelButton
                      onClick={() => {
                        setFieldsDisabled(false);
                      }}
                    >
                      Cancel
                    </Button>

                    <Button 
                      submitButton
                      onClick={onConfirmClick}
                    >
                      Bevestig
                    </Button>
                  </>
                )}

                {!fieldsDisabled && (
                  <Button type="submit" submitButton>
                    Verzend
                  </Button>
                )}
              </FormButtons>
            )}
          </Form>
        )}
      />

      {Boolean(loginCode) && (
        <Formik
          initialValues={{
            message: '',
          }}
          validationSchema={RequestChangeFormSchema}
          onSubmit={onRequestChangeSubmit}
          render={({ handleSubmit, isSubmitting }) => (
            <Section>
              <SectionHeading hasMarginTop>
                Aanvraag om gegevens te wijzigen
              </SectionHeading>

              <FieldsRow>
                <FieldsColumn size='full'>
                  <Field
                    name='message'
                    label='Bericht'
                    placeholder='Vul hier aub de gewijzigde gegevens in'
                    disabled={isSubmitting}
                    component={FormTextAreaField}
                  />
                </FieldsColumn>
              </FieldsRow>

              <Button
                type="submit"
                onClick={handleSubmit}
                disabled={isSubmitting}
                submitButton
              >
                Verzend wijziging
              </Button>
            </Section>
          )}
        />
      )}
    </Wrapper>
  )
};

export default FormPage;
```

Comment: No errors in log... what about the console?

Comment: same, it just won't do... anything. it doesn't even seem to take any action.

Comment: Well, something must have changed in your system. Have you upgraded any libraries or installed new ones? If nothing's happening without errors, it might be some event conflict.

Comment: the composer libraries have been updated. this was an old application which i continued development on but didn't have any documentation or anything on. the used composer libraries(?) are mpdf, myclabs, paragonie, psr and setassign

Comment: Is there a way you could revert them to their old versions before the update to test if the app will work in that case?

Comment: I can try but the reason they were updated in the first place was because the application wouldn't build without the updated composer libraries.

Comment: Well, in that case the only path I see is debugging a whole bunch of vendor code. Start by inspecting the button and see what kinds of events it has attached to it when the page is rendered.

Comment: I am going to revert the package.json and the composer files to the original first files to see if it changes anything.

Comment: I should check in the web page what events pop up in f12?

Comment: Yes, in the inspector you should see a little `event` button next to the element that lists all the events bound to it.

Comment: this is what pops up: https://imgur.com/a/S0URhs3 I also reverted all the libraries in package and composer and it changed nothing.

Comment: Oh dear. I'd start with the obvious ones - click and submit. Go through the source codes and try to see if they're even triggered.

Comment: I will try tomorrow, this is breaking my brain too much right now and i have been struggling with this for a while. I'll keep you updated and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the culprit:

```
first_name: Yup.string().required(`Voornaam leraar is verplich`),
      last_name: Yup.string().required(`Achternaam leraar is verplicht`),
```

this checked for 2 fields which no longer existed! i had removed this part before i rolled back but didn't commit it due to errors. Removed this part and it worked!